# ErpConfigContext and ODataQueryBuilder throw error when trying to connect through Odata service

Tags: java, s4sdk

I am trying to build an app for Cloud solution. When trying to run the app locally, I got error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>
> com/sap/cloud/sdk/odatav2/connectivity/ODataException.

This is running on Java EE 7 Web Profile Tomee 7 server.

```
Apr 22, 2019 3:48:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.center code hereoncurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WorkOrderDemo]]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WorkOrderDemo]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/cloud/sdk/odatav2/connectivity/ODataException
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.OpenEJBContextConfig.configureStart(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:124)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:208)
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
       ... 20 more
 
Apr 22, 2019 3:48:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WorkOrderDemo]]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
       ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WorkOrderDemo]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/cloud/sdk/odatav2/connectivity/ODataException
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.OpenEJBContextConfig.configureStart(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:124)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:208)
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
       ... 20 more
 
Apr 22, 2019 3:48:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
       ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WorkOrderDemo]]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
       ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WorkOrderDemo]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/cloud/sdk/odatav2/connectivity/ODataException
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.OpenEJBContextConfig.configureStart(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:124)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
       ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:208)
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
       ... 20 more
```

Local Destination for the server has been configured as `ErpQueryEndpoint`. `Pom.xml` also includes the `groupID` and `artifactId` for `Odata` connectivity. Packages have been imported.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
                 final ErpConfigContext configContext = new ErpConfigContext(ErpDestination.getDefaultName());
                 try {
                        final List<MyWorkOrderType> workOrders = ODataQueryBuilder
                                .withEntity("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCF_workorder_SRV",
                                        "WorkOrderSet")
                                .select("Aufnr",
                                        "Ktext",
                                        "Auart",
                                        "Asttx")
                                .build()
                                .execute(configContext)
                                .asList(MyWorkOrderType.class);
                 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (ODataException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 }
           }
```

Comment: Please add the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: Can you add the output of `mvn dependency:tree` to your question? It seems like the `com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:odatav2-connectivity` library is missing on your classpath/in your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

As I can see in your code, you are querying a custom OData service of SAP S/4HANA. For OData queries to custom OData services, you might also consider using the [Virtual Data Model (VDM) of the S/4HANA Cloud SDK](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/) instead of ODataQueryBuilder. To use the VDM with a custom OData service, one can use the VDM generator as described in the [following blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/). By the way, it also works for the S/4HANA On-Premise. You can find more details on the customising [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/19/deep-dive-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-s4hana-connectivity-made-simple/).

Comment: I followed the blog and generate VDM. But now I got the compilation error for the generated java at the line import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.OneToOneLink;  WorkOrderOneToOneLink.java:[12,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OneToOneLink. I checked the POM and it looks ok. Any suggestion on this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the `com.sap.cloud.s4hana.datamodel:odata-core` dependency on your classpath? The deep dive blog posts assumes, that you use one of our archetypes to consumer your generated VDM.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. I fixed it by changing the SAP Cloud SDK version in POM to 2.14.0, which is the latest one so far.                  <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.0</version>